# Alexa: Does DynamoDB IAM permissions for Alexa also automatically add a bunch of other AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, alexa-skills-kit

I just created a new dynamoDB IAM policy for lambda. I added only  DynamoFullAccessPermission .

However, in Lambda, it looks like a lot of others services are automatically added?

Does DynamoFullAccessPermission IAM automatically entail this?

[image]

Comment: Okay, why the downvote?

Comment: You should typically include a code snippet in your question, in this case the IAM policy is needed to answer the question.

Comment: Go look at the IAM policy's raw JSON. There's no need to come here and ask us to look at it for you.

Comment: The problem with these enterprise interfaces is that learning where things are or how to look up a policy's json is a learning curve. I had thought they only provided a visual interface for the policy permissions.

Comment: @ina: no worries. AWS is huge and it needs some time until you know where to look. You could have looked this up going to IAM -> Roles and clicking on the Role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could have looked that up yourself, but I'm just learning about AWS myself so I was curious..

Apparently, yes, this role includes a bunch of stuff from EC2, SNS, etc. allow-excerpt from the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess IAM-Role:

```
"Action": [
    "dynamodb:*",
    "dax:*",
    "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
    "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
    "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
    "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
    "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
    "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
    "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
    "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmHistory",
    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
    "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
    "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
    "datapipeline:ActivatePipeline",
    "datapipeline:CreatePipeline",
    "datapipeline:DeletePipeline",
    "datapipeline:DescribeObjects",
    "datapipeline:DescribePipelines",
    "datapipeline:GetPipelineDefinition",
    "datapipeline:ListPipelines",
    "datapipeline:PutPipelineDefinition",
    "datapipeline:QueryObjects",
    "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
    "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
    "iam:GetRole",
    "iam:ListRoles",
    "sns:CreateTopic",
    "sns:DeleteTopic",
    "sns:ListSubscriptions",
    "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
    "sns:ListTopics",
    "sns:Subscribe",
    "sns:Unsubscribe",
    "sns:SetTopicAttributes",
    "lambda:CreateFunction",
    "lambda:ListFunctions",
    "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
    "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
    "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
    "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
    "lambda:DeleteFunction"
],
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "*"
```

On a further look the things outside of Dynamo (`dynamodb`, `dax`) looks all legit to me: EC2 is view-only of network/security, SNS for queuing from/to DynamoDB, etc..

Comment: I guess that is somehow needed to run dynamo with full access